# $V= \{ f \in \mathbb F(\mathbb N) | f(n) = f(n+3)\forall n \geq 0\}$ is a subspace of $F(\mathbb N) $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I must prove that this is a subspace of $\mathbb F (\mathbb N)$ but also find a spanning set of V.

My attempt at the problem : 
I don't understand which functions are part of this subset... I can take $ f(n) = (n-5/2)^2$ which is equal at n=1 and n=4 , but isn't equal $\forall n \in \mathbb N \geq 0$ I would guess constant functions satisfy the criteria ? Such that taking y=c gives always the same output  $\forall n$, then my guess of a spanning set of that would be {1} since it's just a constant function ?

thanks for help.

Comment: what is $\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: The functions youre talking about are functions that repeat their first 3 values ($f(0), f(1), f(2)$) over and over. (I am assuming youre talking about functions from the natural numbers to some other space?) Constant functions do that, but a function that would repeat $1,2,3,1,2,3...$ over and over also does that.

Comment: Your task now is to show that the constant zero function repeats, sums of two repeating functions also repeat, and multiples of repeating functions also repeat (all repetitions every 3 steps). Good luck